# number of free variables and leading variables

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

We know that **a homogeneous linear system in n unknowns whose corresponding augmented matrix has rref form with
r leading 1's has n-r free variables**

What happen if we delete "Homogeneous" ? I have actually already tried it for a lot non homogeneous system which is consistent and i think it's still true for this case . But i am still not sure whether it is true for any system of linear equations which is consistent?

Comment: You've identified in the last line the crucial extra assumption, "which is consistent".  The consistency of a linear system is guaranteed with one that is homogeneous (because of the trivial solution).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the non-homogeneous system is consistent, it will have the same number of free variables as the homogeneous system.

Consider $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$, and let $\mathbf{x}_0$ be a solution. Let $\mathbf{x}_1$ be any other solution. Then $\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_0$ is a solution to the homogeneous system. Since $\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_0$ can be written in terms of (say) $k$ free variables, so can $\mathbf{x}_1$.

Likewise, any solution $\mathbf{n}$ to the homogeneous system gives a unique solution $\mathbf{x}_1=\mathbf{x}_0+\mathbf{n}$ to the non-homogeneous system, so any combination of free variables gives a solution tot he non-homogeneous system.